# Can `_mm256_movemask_ps` be used instead of undefined `_mm256_movemask_epi32`?

Tags: c, simd, avx, avx2

Couldn't find in https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide the needed DWORD counterpart for `_mm256_movemask_epi8`, so my question is whether using AVX float `_mm256_movemask_ps`
is allowed, or how to do it otherwise?

As far as I understand, `_mm256_movemask_epi8` can do the job but the resultant mask is 32bit where I need the mask to be 8bit (a bit for each of the 8 DWORDs).

The fragment with which I wrestle is this:

```
        } else { // Below: haystack >=128; needle >=4; VECTOR

        // Stage 1: SSE2 or AVX2 i.e. 16 or 32 strides.
        // Stage 2: Dealing with the eventual remainder.
        // The main idea: Stressing the registers as it was done in Quadruplet (the above fastest etude) - outperforms Stephen R. van den Berg's strstr at http://www.scs.stanford.edu/histar/src/pkg/uclibc/libc/string/generic/strstr.c
        // __m256i _mm256_cmpeq_epi32 (__m256i a, __m256i b) needs AVX2; the more attractive __mmask8 _mm256_cmpeq_epi32_mask (__m256i a, __m256i b) needs AVX512??
        
// Pattern: "Linus Torvalds" 
// Order4:            [    ] skip 32 if not a single occurrence of 'alds' within YMM + (Order - 1) = 32 + 3 = 35 bytes window:
// Haystack:                                 "otto.......................Torvalds" 
// YMM HaystackVector1:                      "otto.......................Torva" 
// YMM HaystackVector2:                      "tto.......................Torval" 
// YMM HaystackVector3:                      "to.......................Torvald" 
// YMM HaystackVector4:                      "o.......................Torvalds" 
// YMM Vector1:                              "aldsaldsaldsaldsaldsaldsaldsalds" 
// 
// Mask1=(HaystackVector1 eqd Vector1):       0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0     ! 8bit !
// Mask2=(HaystackVector2 eqd Vector1):       0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0     ! 8bit !
// Mask3=(HaystackVector3 eqd Vector1):       0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0     ! 8bit !
// Mask4=(HaystackVector4 eqd Vector1):       0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1     ! 8bit !
// Result=(Mask1 OR Mask2 OR Mask3 OR Mask4): 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1     ! 8bit !

    size_t YMMchunks = cbTarget/32 -1; // in here, ensured at least 4 chunks; in order to avoid past haystack YMM reads - decrease 1 chunk and finish with Scalar_Quadruplet
    const __m256i last4 = _mm256_set1_epi32(pbPattern[cbPattern - 1 -3]);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < YMMchunks; i += 32) {

    const __m256i HaystackVector1 = _mm256_loadu_si256((const __m256i*)(pbTarget + i + 0));
    const __m256i HaystackVector2 = _mm256_loadu_si256((const __m256i*)(pbTarget + i + 1));
    const __m256i HaystackVector3 = _mm256_loadu_si256((const __m256i*)(pbTarget + i + 2));
    const __m256i HaystackVector4 = _mm256_loadu_si256((const __m256i*)(pbTarget + i + 3));

    const __m256i EQD1 = _mm256_cmpeq_epi32(HaystackVector1, last4);
    const __m256i EQD2 = _mm256_cmpeq_epi32(HaystackVector2, last4);
    const __m256i EQD3 = _mm256_cmpeq_epi32(HaystackVector3, last4);
    const __m256i EQD4 = _mm256_cmpeq_epi32(HaystackVector4, last4);

    const __m256i FinalVector12 = _mm256_or_si256(EQD1, EQD2);
    const __m256i FinalVector34 = _mm256_or_si256(EQD3, EQD4);

    uint32_t mask = _mm256_movemask_epi8(_mm256_or_si256(FinalVector12, FinalVector34));
    //uint8_t mask = _mm256_movemask_ps(_mm256_or_si256(FinalVector12, FinalVector34)); //AVX is 8x4float _mm256_movemask_ps, couldn't find _mm256_movemask_epi32 ! Is it allowed?

    // ...

    }

    // ...

        } //if (cbTarget<128) {
```

Comment: Yes, this is possible, but you need to cast the `__m256i` to a `__m256` using [`_mm256_castsi256_ps`](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#techs=AVX,AVX2&text=_mm256_castsi256_ps)

Comment: Thank you, didn't know there were a cast function:
`uint8_t mask = _mm256_movemask_ps( _mm256_castsi256_ps(_mm256_or_si256(FinalVector12, FinalVector34)) );`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works fine, you just need `_mm256_castsi256_ps`. Same for 64-bit integers, cast to vector of doubles and use `_mm256_movemask_pd`.

Another alternative, if you have [BMI2 support](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_manipulation_instruction_set#Supporting_CPUs), you can use `_mm256_movemask_epi8`, then `_pext_u32` with the mask `0x88888888` to drop the bits you don't need and pack the remaining 8 bits into the byte. However, that instruction is only fast on Intel, on AMD it's decoded into many micro-ops and takes almost 20 CPU cycles.

Comment: Thanks, will use:

`uint8_t mask = _mm256_movemask_ps( _mm256_castsi256_ps(_mm256_or_si256(FinalVector12, FinalVector34)) );`

I wanted to use the direct `__mmask8 _mm256_cmpeq_epi32_mask (__m256i a, __m256i b)`, but requiring AVX512VL or AVX512F!

I don't have such CPU, yet, consider buying i3-1005G1... in a black friday.

Comment: `vpmovmskb` + `pext` is obviously worse even on Intel than `vmovmskps` (which at worst might have an extra 1 cycle of bypass-delay latency if the input is coming from a vec-int instruction.)  If you're going to mention `pext` it at all, you should be point out that there's no way it can be as good, even in the best case.

Comment: The actual alternative is usually to handle the redundant bit-duplication in a `pmovmskb` result, e.g. bit-scan and then divide by 4.  Or check `== 0xffffffff` instead of `== 0xff` to check that all bits are set; those are equally efficient in asm.  (@Georgi appears to be using an `if()` on the mask so could probably change the condition, if you're not actually storing the result anywhere like a bitmap array.)

Comment: @Georgi: Or sometimes it's worth using 2x `vpackssdw` + `vpacksswb` to pack 4 dword vectors down to one byte vector for `vpmovmskb`, especially if it's ok for lane order to get mixed up.  But usually in a search loop you'd just OR or AND some conditions together and see if the thing you're looking for was in any vector, and if so then check one at a time.  (e.g. in a search loop looking for a dword array element that matched a key.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Thank you, you are ahead, I still struggle with ropes, yes, the idea is to effectively write this etude - it is a challenge for a beginner like me to not make brutal inefficiencies. Please jump in, if you see a way to help, this function is for people to use it freely, every optimization is welcome and appreciated. I had some high hopes with MPSADBW, which calculates eight Manhattan distances, but work of http://0x80.pl/articles/simd-strfind.html showed the implementation takes too many cycles, so more fun for us :P

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks to this thread I managed to write XMM/YMM/ZMM variants of Boyer-Moore-Horspool order 4, incoming in 10 days or so. Will appreciate any hint on how to boost it, regards:  
https://www.overclock.net/threads/cpu-benchmark-finding-linus-torvalds.1754066/page-2#post-28644885